# How do I use JOptionPane.showInputDialog with an array?

Tags: java

I've tried just using the string instead of the number in the array but it still won't work.

```java
String [] seller  = { "Yeah", "Nah" ,"Depends on what it is"};
      seller = (String[]) JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Hey, you want to see something cool","Scam3r69 has entered chat", 1, null, seller, seller[1]); 

if (seller.equals(seller[2])){
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Just let me say what it is okay");
}
else{
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"It's a chance to make 1 million dollars in 1 minute");  
}
```

I want it to be so when they pick "Nah" a message is displayed and if they pick anything else I want a different one to be displayed.

> run: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   practice.pkg3.Practice3.main(Practice3.java:28)
>   /Users/alexanderkiknadze/Library/Caches/NetBeans/8.2/executor-snippets/run.xml:53:
>   Java returned: 1 BUILD FAILED (total time: 12 seconds)

Comment: Also I'm pretty new to java so if I'm missing anything obvious I'm sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are passing String[] to your JOptionPane.showInputDialog. So based on the selection you will get a String and not a String [] . Sof you should change your code

```
seller = (String[]) JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Hey, you want to see something cool","Scam3r69 has entered chat", 1, null, seller, seller[1]);
```

to

```
String sellerInput = (String) JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Hey, you want to see something cool","Scam3r69 has entered chat", 1, null, seller, seller[1]);
```

and `seller.equals(seller[2])` to `sellerInput.equals(seller[2])` so that it will check the input from the dialog box with the array.

Comment: Thank you, seriously appreciate it I was really stuck on that.

Comment: please go though this and accept the answer as it might help others in future.- https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers